# UIView not compressed after removal of a bigger view with auto-layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have the following view hierarchy:

```
- containerView: UIView
    - customViewPlaceholder: UIView
    - label: UILabel
```

1. `containerView` is fixed width, and relies on the height of the subviews to get its height (inner views "push out" the height).
2. `customViewPlaceholder` and `label` are glued to the edges of the container view with 4 zero-length constraints, and occupy the same rectangle.
3. Initially `customViewPlaceholder` is empty, so `containerView` has the height of the label.

It behaves as I expect when I add a view into `customViewPlaceholder` programmatically (adding the view itself + 4 zero-length constraints to glue it to the edges of `customViewPlaceholder`): height of the `containerView` expands. However when I remove it, view size stays the same.

How do I make `containerView` auto-compress back to the height of the label when custom view is removed?

Comment: How is hugging and compression configured?

Comment: You probably need to bump the hugging priority up so that the view lay outing is forced to hug as tight as possible and also not allow compression of the content.